# Windows - Custom Lock Screen link to custom App?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Would anyone be able to point me to docs/api that allow me to put a custom 
button or link on windows lock screen ?

I want to be able to launch a custom program from there.

Thanks.

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean on "lock screen" ?
You can just run:
**rundll32 USER32.DLL,LockWorkStation**
This will lock the current user, but doesn't log off.
You can run it in "cmd" or "Run (Start Menu)"
OR... if using C, VB, Delphi, others... you can just call function "LockWorkStation" at USER32.DLL, and remember it's case sensitive.

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to customize the lock screen, not lock the workstation

Comment: OHH... my bad, had to read it twice. Sorry, and thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score -1):

It is highly unlikely that Microsoft would readily allow you to do something like that because it would be a security loophole of note. The point is that if no one is currently authorised to use the machine, it shouldn't be possible to run programs. Suddenly despite your best and honest intentions - your program becomes a potential backdoor to hack into machines.

The only kind of custom "application" MS might allow from the login screen would be alternate authentication mechanisms (e.g. fingerprint reader).
These would probably be implemented at the driver level, and have to interact with a very specific API.  Even then, I doubt such a driver would be allowed to run an arbitrary application.

You may want to rather consider having your application run on a schedule or as a service without user interaction.